# How can I sort my items and headers when I drag and drop them in Swift using Core Data, and the SourceIndexPath does not seem to work?

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I correctly sort my items and headers when I drag and drop them in Swift using Core Data and get the correct item when using an index path?

The issue that I am having is that my sorting algorithm is not correctly pulling out the correct rows and sections in my collection view (I am getting index out of range errors on the line with the stride function).  I would like to be able to drag rows and drop them with their order to save as well as drag and drop headers to reorder them and save their order.

The issue seems to occur when assigning a value to the 'upper' and 'lower' variables, as well as striding to get a value for the new order property of my core data entity.  It seems that there is an issue when trying to get the dragged item by using the SourceIndexPath.section and SourceIndexPath.item.

**View where I am trying to get the drag and drop working.**

```
import UIKit


class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var fromItem: Item
    
    init(item: Item) {
        self.fromItem = item
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    var dataSourceSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Header, ListData>()
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Header, ListData>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGroupedBackground
        
        var layoutConfig = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
        layoutConfig.headerMode = .firstItemInSection
        let listLayout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: layoutConfig)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: listLayout)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        
        collectionView.dragDelegate = self
        collectionView.dropDelegate = self
        collectionView.dragInteractionEnabled = true
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addNewHeader))
       
        let headers = fromItem.headers?.allObjects as? [Header] ?? []
        print("headers here \(headers)")
        dataSourceSnapshot.appendSections(headers.sorted(by: {$0.order < $1.order}))
        dataSource.apply(dataSourceSnapshot)
        
        for header in headers.sorted(by: {$0.order < $1.order}) {
            
            let children = header.children!.allObjects as? [Child] ?? []
            let sortedChildren = children.sorted{$0.order > $1.order}
            
            var dataSourceSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ListData>()
            let headerItem = ListData.header(header)
            dataSourceSnapshot.append([headerItem])
            
            for child in sortedChildren {
                dataSourceSnapshot.append([.child(child)], to: headerItem)
            }
            
            dataSourceSnapshot.expand([headerItem])
            
            dataSource.apply(dataSourceSnapshot, to: header, animatingDifferences: false)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func addNewHeader() {
        var order: Double = 0
        let header = fromItem.headers?.allObjects as? [Header] ?? []
        if header.count > 0 {
            order = header.last!.order + 25
        } else {
            order = 100
        }
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let newHeader = Header(context: context)
        newHeader.name = "Header"
        newHeader.id = UUID()
        newHeader.order = order
        newHeader.item = fromItem
        
        var childOrder: Double = 0
        let firstChild = header.first(where: {$0.id == newHeader.id })?.children?.allObjects as? [Child] ?? []
        
        if header.count > 0 && firstChild.count > 0 {
            childOrder = firstChild.last!.order + 25
        } else {
            childOrder = 100
        }

        
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ListData>()
        
        dataSourceSnapshot.appendSections([newHeader])
        
        let headerItem = ListData.header(newHeader)
        snapshot.append([headerItem])
        
        var childOrderIncrement = childOrder
        for i in 1...4 {
            let child = Child(context: context)
            child.order = childOrderIncrement
            child.name = "child \(i)"
            child.id = UUID()
            child.header = newHeader
            snapshot.append([.child(child)], to: headerItem)
            childOrderIncrement += 25
        }
        
        snapshot.expand([headerItem])
        
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, to: newHeader, animatingDifferences: false)
        try? context.save()
        
        print("Headers = \(fromItem.headers?.allObjects as? [Header] ?? [])")
    }
}

extension DetailViewController: UICollectionViewDragDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        guard let item = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else {
            collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
            return [UIDragItem]()
        }
        
        switch item {
        case .header(let header):
            let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: header.objectID.uriRepresentation().absoluteURL as NSURL)
            
            let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
            
            return [dragItem]
            
        case .child(let child):
            let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: NSString(string: child.id!.uuidString))
            
            let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
            
            return [dragItem]
        }
    }
    
    
func DetailViewController(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForAddingTo session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> [UIDragItem] {
    guard let item = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) else {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        return [UIDragItem]()
    }
    
    switch item {
    case .header(_):
        
        return [UIDragItem]()
    case .child(let child):
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: NSString(string: child.id!.uuidString))
        
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        
        return [dragItem]
    }
}
}

extension DetailViewController: UICollectionViewDropDelegate {
    
    private func reorderItems(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        let items = coordinator.items
        if items.count == 1, let item = items.first, let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath {
            var destIndexPath = destinationIndexPath
            if destIndexPath.item >= collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: destIndexPath.section) {
                destIndexPath.item = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: destIndexPath.section) - 1
            }
            guard let fromChild = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: sourceIndexPath),
                  sourceIndexPath != destIndexPath else { return }
            
            var snap = dataSource.snapshot()
            let header = dataSource.sectionIdentifier(for: destIndexPath.section)!
            let sourceHeader = dataSource.sectionIdentifier(for: sourceIndexPath.section)!
            
            
            switch fromChild {
            case .header(_):
                print("cannot reorder headers here")
            case .child(let fromChild):
                snap.deleteItems([.child(fromChild)])
                
                if let toChild = dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: destIndexPath) {
                    switch toChild {
                    case .header(_):
                        print("cannot reorder headers here")
                        
                    case .child(let toChild):
                        let isAfter = destIndexPath.item > sourceIndexPath.item
                        if isAfter {
                            if header == sourceHeader {
                                snap.insertItems([.child(fromChild)], afterItem: .child(toChild))
                                
                            } else {
                                snap.insertItems([.child(fromChild)], afterItem: .child(toChild))
                                
                            }
                        } else {
                            snap.insertItems([.child(fromChild)], beforeItem: .child(toChild))
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    snap.appendItems([.child(fromChild)], toSection: header)
                }
                
            }
            
            var upper: Double
            var lower: Double
            
            let headers = fromItem.headers?.allObjects as? [Header] ?? []
            let children = headers[destIndexPath.section].children!.allObjects as? [Child] ?? []
            let sortedChildren = children.sorted{$0.order > $1.order}
            
            
            if destIndexPath.item == sortedChildren.count {
                print("Appending to the end of the list")
                lower = sortedChildren.last?.order ?? 0
                upper = sortedChildren.last?.order ?? 0 + 100.0
            } else if destIndexPath.item == 0 {
                print("Inserting into the beginning")
                lower = 0.0
                
                upper = sortedChildren.first?.order ?? 100.0
            } else {
                print("Inserting into the middle of the list")
                
                upper = sortedChildren[destIndexPath.item - 2].order
                lower = sortedChildren[destIndexPath.item - 1].order
            }
            print(upper)
            print(lower)
            
            
            if header != sourceHeader {
                
                sortedChildren[sourceIndexPath.item].header = header
            }
            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
            appDelegate.saveContext()
            
            dataSource.apply(snap, animatingDifferences: false)
            
            for header in headers.sorted(by: {$0.order < $1.order}) {
                
                let children = header.children!.allObjects as? [Child] ?? []
                let sortedChildren = children.sorted{$0.order > $1.order}
                
                var dataSourceSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ListData>()
                let headerItem = ListData.header(header)
                dataSourceSnapshot.append([headerItem])
                
                for child in sortedChildren {
                    dataSourceSnapshot.append([.child(child)], to: headerItem)
                }
                
                dataSourceSnapshot.expand([headerItem])
                
                dataSource.apply(dataSourceSnapshot, to: header, animatingDifferences: false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func reorderHeaders(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        let items = coordinator.items
        if items.count == 1, let item = items.first, let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath {
            
            guard let fromHeader = dataSource.sectionIdentifier(for: sourceIndexPath.section),
                  sourceIndexPath != destinationIndexPath else { return }
            
            var snap = dataSource.snapshot()
            
            let unsortedHeaders = fromItem.headers?.allObjects as? [Header] ?? []
            let headers = unsortedHeaders.sorted{$0.order > $1.order}
            
            let children = fromHeader.children!.allObjects as? [Child] ?? []
            let sortedChildren = children.sorted{$0.order > $1.order}

            for i in sortedChildren {
                snap.deleteItems([.child(i)])
            }
            snap.deleteSections([fromHeader])
            
            if let toHeader = dataSource.sectionIdentifier(for: destinationIndexPath.section) {
                let isAfter = destinationIndexPath.section > sourceIndexPath.section
                
                if isAfter {
                    snap.insertSections([fromHeader], afterSection: toHeader)
                } else {
                    snap.insertSections([fromHeader], beforeSection: toHeader)
                }
                
            } else {
                snap.appendSections([fromHeader])
            }
            
            var upper: Double
            var lower: Double
            
            if destinationIndexPath.item == headers.count {
                print("Appending to the end of the list")
                lower = headers.last!.order
                upper = headers.last!.order + 100.0
            } else if destinationIndexPath.item == 0 {
                print("Inserting into the beginning")
                lower = 0.0
                upper = headers.first?.order ?? 100.0
            } else {
                print("Inserting into the middle of the list")
                upper = headers[destinationIndexPath.section - 1].order
                lower = headers[destinationIndexPath.section].order
            }
            
            headers[sourceIndexPath.section].order = stride(from: lower, to: upper, by: (upper - lower) / Double(2)).map{ $0 }[1]
            
            guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
            appDelegate.saveContext()
            
            for header in headers.sorted(by: {$0.order < $1.order}) {
                
                let children = header.children!.allObjects as? [Child] ?? []
                let sortedChildren = children.sorted{$0.order > $1.order}
                
                var dataSourceSnapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<ListData>()
                let headerItem = ListData.header(header)
                dataSourceSnapshot.append([headerItem])
                
                for child in sortedChildren {
                    dataSourceSnapshot.append([.child(child)], to: headerItem)
                }
                
                dataSourceSnapshot.expand([headerItem])
                
                dataSource.apply(dataSourceSnapshot, to: header, animatingDifferences: false)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath
        
        if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
            destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        } else {
            let section = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
            let row = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
            destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(item: row, section: section)
        }
        
        switch coordinator.proposal.operation {
        case .move:
            for item in coordinator.items {
                if item.dragItem.localObject as! String == "child" {
                    coordinator.session.loadObjects(ofClass: NSString.self) { items in
                        

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            print("reordering the children")
                            
                            self.reorderItems(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
                        }
                }
                } else {
                    coordinator.session.loadObjects(ofClass: NSURL.self) { items in
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            print("reordering the headers")
                            
                            self.reorderHeaders(coordinator: coordinator, destinationIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, collectionView: collectionView)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            break
        case .copy:
            return
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
    }
    
    
}
```

**My Core Data Model:**

[image]

[image]

If you have any further questions, please do not hesitate to ask.

If it would make it easier, I could send you my entire Xcode project.

Answer (score 1):

In my apps I do it the following way:

1. get current list of objects, which is ordered by a Core Data record
2. remove an object with an indexPath from `UICollectionViewDragDelegate` (collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath))
3. insert this object back in the list at destination indexPath from `UICollectionViewDropDelegate` (collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator))
4. update Core Data values indexes with updated sort indexes

Code example:

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDragDelegate
extension CombinedMainVC: UICollectionViewDragDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarCC, let item = cell.calendar, let name = item.name else { return [UIDragItem]() }
        startingIndexPath = indexPath
        let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: name as NSString)
        let dragItem = UIDragItem(itemProvider: itemProvider)
        dragItem.localObject = item
        return [dragItem]
    }
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDropDelegate
extension CombinedMainVC: UICollectionViewDropDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
        let forbidden = UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .forbidden)
        guard destinationIndexPath?.section == startingIndexPath.section else { return forbidden }
        return collectionView.hasActiveDrag ? UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath) : forbidden
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
        guard let destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath else { return }
        
        var calendars = fetchedRC.fetchedObjects!
        let list = calendars.remove(at: startingIndexPath.row)
        calendars.insert(list, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
        
        for cal in fetchedRC.fetchedObjects! {
            let sortIndex = calendars.firstIndex(of: cal)!
            cal.secondData = Int32(sortIndex)
        }
        
        updated = false
        appDelegate.saveContext()
        postNotification("dateChanged")
    }
}
```

(force unwrappings are done because drop session can't be started if there are no calendars)

After that my model is updated and I could apply a new snapshot to the collection view. I think you should order your objects in one place (when you applying snapshots, for example) and in drag-and-drop session you need just to change your data model and do not touch collection view snapshot.

You could use the same approach for Headers and Childs - the only difference is in list of objects you will in use in point 1

Comment: Thank you Viktor.  Would you be able to look at my code above to see if my logic when appending to the end, inserting in the middle, or inserting in the beginning of my collection view list is valid.  If it helps I could send you my entire Xcode project.

Comment: @Nighthawk Sure

Comment: Thanks Viktor.  If you would like a copy of my Xcode project, do you have an email that I can send it to?  My main issue seems to be getting the correct item using the destination and source index path.  I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: mail@viktorgavrilov.com

Comment: just sent you an email.